# Get the next date from column of dates

Tags: mac, numbers

I have a table in Numbers with a column which contains dates. From that column, I'm trying to get the next date from *today* from that list and display it in a cell.

[image: Column]

Assuming today is **October 12, 2019**, I'm expecting the value in the cell to display `2019-10-31`.

I've been trying for hours, but I couldn't figure it out. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to add an additional column or anything like that, just a simple (or complex) formula to place in the cell.

**Edit:**
To clarify, the date values are entered manually and they are dates of an event. What I'm trying to achieve is in another table for the upcoming date of the next event.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231131/getting-the-first-cell-not-containing-certain-text-in-numbers?rq=1 See this AppleScript and change the part where it compares the text to the date. Hope you're able to to figure out how to compare dates. This one handles dates too https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303112/numbers-find-a-cell-in-a-table-lookup-using-multiple-criteria?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, assuming the dates are in column B of Table 1. The MATCH function returns 3, the location of 9/30, which is the date before the match. Add 1. Then use INDEX to get the value of cell 4.

INDEX(Table 1::B,MATCH(NOW(),Table 1::B)+1)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that did it!!